# Translation of "whoever saves one life saves the world entire"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, sentence-translation

I am very interested in this translation. Google spits out "quicumque salvat unam vitam, totum mundum salvat". I am wondering if this is correct as I have seen google translate fail sometimes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the given quote is based on an original quote in the Mishna (Sanhedrin 4:5) to which we already have [a Latin translation](https://books.google.com/books?id=VgVcAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=iw#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Si quis animam ex Israele unam perdat, haberi in Scriptura, quasi integrum mundum destruxisset: itemque **qui unam servet, quasi totum mundum conservasset.** ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=gCGrnW80urkC&pg=PA414&lpg=PA414&dq=%22unam%20perdat%22%20quasi&source=bl&ots=1qikTMnkeo&sig=ACfU3U12XhlFjSEWFZGtcd-JdX4at-Rp_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv09z15pz8AhUXQ_EDHZ6VDRIQ6AF6BAgHEAM#v=onepage&q=%22unam%20perdat%22%20quasi&f=false))

When compared to the Google Translate suggestion:

1. the human translator here preferred *anima* to *vita*, which might be influenced by the original (which is rather *soul* and not *life*). I believe both are defendable but I prefer *anima* to signify life in this context which really means living being rather than an abstract term - which fits nicely to the [definition](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=anima&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059). Also when Grotius says "ah!, *vitam perdidi* operose nihil agendo" (alas!, I have lost my life in laboring over nothing) he doesn't mean that he killed someone or died but rather that he wasted life.
2. *quasi* - again this comes from the original to mean "as if" (i.e., *as if* one saves the entire world) .This is indeed optional.
3. Google Translate used *salvo* which is not attest in classical Latin and its meaning is quite similar to *servo*. So either is fine.
4. *quicumque* vs. *qui* basically is *whoever* vs. *(one) who/which*. I think both are fine.
5. word order in Latin is quite loose. Hence you see in Google Translate both "salvat unam vitam" (verb-object) and "totum mundum salvat* (object-verb). In as much as we can speak of regular/ordinary/natural order, we can say usually it is subject-object-verb. But again, the composer -in order to emphasise few things- might choose different order.
6. One last bit of information: Google Translate uses the verb in the indicative present form while the other translation is subjective present. Both are fine. I even tend to go with the machine this time. Very generally roughly speaking when we use subjunctive is "of conditions assumed in statement, but implied not to be actual; the verb in pres. (rarely perf.) implies that the condition is still possible;" while going with the indicative would generally indicate "conditions which are assumed to be true, with the verb in pres. or perf." ([L&S source](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Si&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)) .

All in, we can go with:

> quicumque unam animam servat/salvat, [quasi] totum mundum servat/salvat.

Comment: Thank you so much. Being completely illiterate in latin,     I assume the original quote referred here is based on one of the versions where the emphasis is on the soul being Jewish. I am looking for the generic version. Does this makes sense "qui servet unam anima, totum mundum servet"? Thanks again

Comment: @Anon_user, thanks for accepting the answer, but you might want to wait some time to see if other answers/comments come along.

Comment: good idea, removing the accepted answer for now, although looks pretty good to my very naive eyes.

Comment: I think the subjunctive is probably right here -- this is a relative clause of characteristic, rather than one with a definite antecedent.

Comment: @TKR, maybe, what would be the constract for the indicative (someone specifit)? I think I saw several instances when the simple indicative was used in mottos. like  *qui nescit tacere, nescit et loqui*

Comment: Hmm, looking into it further it looks like both moods do get used after *quicumque*, with the contrast being something like that between a present general and a future less vivid condition, so possibly either is OK here.

Comment: @TKR, Something elusive there for me. Sometimes I think I get hold of that, and then it disappears. I've just read [A&G](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/clauses-characteristic) on this. It seems quite subtle. From what I understand in our case the indicative is a little better because "who saves life" is a matter of fact. That man who saves life, etc. Not That man "of such a character to save life".  It is not defining the man, it states what one does. But again not sure. very confusing.

Comment: @d_e: Verb "conservaset" doesn't appear in the conjugation table for "conservo": is it a short-form version of "conservavisset"? Is this similar to a mixed-conditional sentence: "if he saves the one, it's as if he would have saved the whole world"?

Comment: @tony it’s a typo: the correct form is conservasset. Yes, it’s a syncopated form. Yes, it’s a contrary-to-fact conditional working with quasi.

Comment: @Kingshorsey, thanks. my typo. fixed this now.

Comment: @d_e, I think I can now safely go with
"quicumque unam animam servat, totum mundum servat."

Comment: @d_e: The unidentified, mythical person, in the quote, hasn't yet done anything. There is only the potential consequence of a possible action. Given these vagaries, what can the verbs be but subjunctive?